# unexpected JPA results

Tags: orm, jpa, join, jpql

Im learning JPA and having problems. My main problem is when i join my entitys and dont quite understand why im getting the results i am .. and its realy slowing my progress if someone could help i would be very greatful.

Entitys

College

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name=College.allCollegeQuery,query="SELECT col FROM College col"),
    @NamedQuery(name=College.collegeStudentJoinQuery,query="SELECT DISTINCT col FROM College col JOIN FETCH col.students"),
    @NamedQuery(name=College.collegeStudentBasicJoinQuery,query="SELECT col FROM College col JOIN col.students s")
})
public class College {

    public static final String allCollegeQuery = "allCollegeQuery";
    public static final String collegeStudentJoinQuery = "collegeStudentJoinQuery";
    public static final String collegeStudentBasicJoinQuery = "collegeStudentBasicJoinQuery";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="college")
    private List<Student> students;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
}
```

Student

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name=Student.allStudentsQuery, query="SELECT stu FROM Student stu"),
    @NamedQuery(name=Student.studentsCollageQuery, query="SELECT stu.college FROM Student stu WHERE stu.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name=Student.studentsWithCollageIDQuery, query="SELECT stu FROM Student stu WHERE stu.college.id = :id")
})
public class Student {

    public static final String allStudentsQuery = "allStudentsquery";
    public static final String studentsCollageQuery = "studentsCollageQuery";
    public static final String studentsWithCollageIDQuery = "studentsCollagewithIDQuery";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private College college;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public College getCollege() {
        return college;
    }
    @XmlTransient
        public void setCollege(College college) {
            this.college = college;
        }
    }
```

Ok so my goal is to query all college's and to return all the students related to them.
Which i was expecting my named query to do

```
SELECT col FROM College col JOIN col.students s
```

My responce was (invoked via glassfish Tester interface)

```
    <return>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>"Bournemouth</name>
    </return>
    <return>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>"Bournemouth</name>
    </return>
    <return>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>"Bournemouth</name>
    </return>
    <return>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>"Bournemouth</name>
    </return>
```

As you can imagen this college only exists once in the database, but i know there are four students attached to this college entity (which i guess why it has repeated). 
The solution i and kind of hoping for would be somthing like (in a sudo xml kind way)

```
<return>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>Bournemouth</name>
   <students>
     <student>
     </student>
    </students>
</return>
```

any help tips or pointers would be greatfuly recived
Thanks

--------------------------- Additional Info ------------------------------

So i performed the SQL logging as Pascal kindly suggested which upon calling the method genorates

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.NAME, t0.ID, t0.NAME, t0.college_Id FROM STUDENT t0, COLLEGE t1 WHERE (t0.college_Id = t1.ID)
```

I also tested the above script in my DB and its results are as i would expect JPA to return.

```
ID    name              id       name     col_id 
1   "Bournemouth    2   James   1
1   "Bournemouth    3   Rich    1
1   "Bournemouth    1   Jon 1
1   "Bournemouth    4   tom 1
```

so i guess this means there must be a problem in my JPA setup? 
as its obviously not repacking the results correctly.

Thanks Again

----------- Update ---------------------------
Further from Pascals suggestions i printed the data to the server log to cut out the 
Tester interface.

```
    public List<College> getCollageWithStudents(){
    List<College> s = null;
    try{
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(College.collegeStudentBasicJoinQuery);
        s = query.getResultList();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
                College c = (College) s.get(i);
                System.out.println("College "+c.getId() + "  "+c.getName());
                System.out.println("Amt Students: "+c.getStudents().size());
                for (int j = 0; j < c.getStudents().size(); j++) {
                    Student stu = (Student) c.getStudents().get(j);
                    System.out.println(stu.getId() + "  "+stu.getName());
                }
            }
    }catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return s;
 }
```

The result are as the should be but this is still not reflected in the Glassfish interface.

```
INFO: College 1  "Bournemouth
INFO: Amt Students: 4
INFO: 2  James
INFO: 3  Rich
INFO: 1  Jon
INFO: 4  tom
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current query is doing an INNER JOIN and thus returns rows when there is at least one match in both tables. In other words, you'll get the `College` of each `Student` that has a `College` (and this explains why you are getting 4 times the the *Bournemouth* here).

What about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c 
FROM College c JOIN FETCH c.students
```

That would return distinct `College` having `Student` (and **fetch** the association).

Comment: Thanks for the responce Pascal, i have treid the above it only seams to be completing College part of the query, in other words its not doing to fetch part.

Comment: @Jon I suggest activating SQL logging to see what is happening exactly but I'm 100% sure this query does fetch the students too (i.e. you get a College with its Students loaded).

Comment: @Pascal i have added sql logging with my results added to the above query. Thanks

Comment: @Jon So as we can see, the students are fetched (and the `college.students` should be loaded if you put a breakpoint). Now, the question is: how are you doing the XML serialization exactly?

Comment: @Pascal well its being called throught the Glassfish tester interface (where you can call WSDL methods) which genorates a soap request and returns the responce. So im not realy doing anything presonaly. would you like me to post my method call?

Comment: @Jon Oh, yes, right, I forgot you were using the Tester interface. What do you get when bypassing the web service layer?

Comment: @Pascal sorry i dont follow you? what would you like me to do? thanks for keeping with me

Comment: @Jon I meant doing a direct Java call, not through the tester interface. From my point of view, the query is correct, the returned result should be correct. I just don't know where the glitch is introduced so I propose to not use the tester interface for now.

Comment: @Pascal i have updated the above and we have some results. It would appear that for some reason the tester interface does parse the soap responce correctly. Do you know of somthing i can use as an alternative to test my web services localy? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jon Maybe your IDE offers some similar feature (AFAIK, Eclipse and NetBeans do). But it's a weird issue.